# In PHP how can I detect code is being run from command line?

Tags: command-line-interface

When I run my PHP script from the command line I get the following notices.  I assume the reason is that these variables such SERVER_NAME are not applicable when running without a browser.

In my code how can I detect that it is run from command line and skip those lines, so I dont have to see these notices?

I dont want to block these notices by piping to /dev/null, I would rather enhance the PHP code.

```
david@ubuntu:/var/www/user$ php cron_email.php
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SERVER_NAME in /var/www/user/codestart.php on line 14
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR in /var/www/user/codestart.php on line 97
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: REQUEST_URI in /var/www/user/codestart.php on line 99
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER in /var/www/user/codestart.php on line 100
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: REQUEST_METHOD in /var/www/user/codestart.php on line 101
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in /var/www/user/codestart.php on line 102
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check `php_sapi_name()`.  If it `=='cli'`, then you are calling from the command line.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php

Answer (score 0):

You could check for `$_SERVER["SHELL"]` or `$_SERVER["TERM"]`.  They should exist for the cli but not when served by your webserver.